# Error when doing a docker ps

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I have Docker installed and it runs fine, but when I have created a container and run it, I want to know the ID of the container, so I do a `docker ps`. But then I always get this message:

```
Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.15/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: I got the same error, but fixed it with 
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://$(boot2docker ip):2375

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure boot2docker is running:

```
$boot2docker start
```

make sure docker host variable is exposed:

```
# Will print boot2docker VM IP
boot2docker ip
The VM's Host only interface IP address is: 192.168.59.103

# Set docker host variable with value from previous command
export DOCKER_HOST tcp://192.168.59.103:2375
```

Check if the docker daemon  is running on the boot2docker host

```
boot2docker ssh
ps aux | grep docker
/usr/local/bin/docker -d ....
```

If you are running on Linux make sure you are running as root user

Comment: Or `boot2docker start` and then `$(boot2docker shellinit)`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you export the docker environment variables:

where it says

after you run

`boot2docker start`

and it says:

`To connect the Docker client to the Docker daemon, please set:
    export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/jbielick/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm
    export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
    export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376`

You need to export those variables. Check that they are empty with

`echo $DOCKER_HOST`

and if it's blank, docker can't talk to your VM.

Comment: FYI: you don't get the exports with `restart`. You have to stop it and then start it